# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Internal Status remains "Started" even after it completes

Tags: sharepoint-addin, workflow-manager

I got a weird issue. I did not see this issue during development on single server farm. But I got it on multi server farm. Let me give a brief about my server farm.

- 1 Application with Search server (Workflow manager installed on this server), 1 WFE with Distributed Cache server and 1 Database server
- SharePoint 2016 with Feature Pack 2
- Workflow Manager 1.0 with CU3, Workflow Manager Client 1.0 with CU3 and Service Bus 1.1

I did continuously 5 tests and out of 5 only for 2 tests the workflow internal status became "**Completed**" and for remaining, stuck at "**Started**" even though workflow executes all steps successfully. I have 38 workflows and it is happening for all. I tried to trace the issue using event viewer and in ULS logs but no luck.

Please note, all my workflows are SharePoint Hosted Add-in workflows (Integrated apps, deployed on Host-Web).

Please help.